# Sports statistics controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mvc, controller

Is there too much logic in this controller (should I migrate them to the model)? How else can it be refactored?

```
class StatsController < ActionController::Base

    def create
        @stats = Stat.receive_stats(STATS_SOURCE)
        sport_type = @stats["sportsID"]

        Stat.categories.each do |category|
            @stats["#{category}"].each do |stat|
                Player.store_stats(stat, sport_type, category) 
            end
        end
        render './index'
    end

    def show
        queried_stats = Stat.queried_stats

        @players_query.each do |player|
            queried_player = Player.find_by(name: player)
            queried_player_stats = Stat.get_stats_of(queried_player)
            if queried_player   
                Stat.categories.each do |category|
                    queried_stats[:"#{category}"] << queried_player_stats["#{category}"] unless queried_player_stats["#{category}"] == nil
                end
            end
        end
        @queried_stats = queried_stats.to_json
        render './show'
    end
end
```

Comment: There isn't a single reference to `params`, which is weird. We don't know what `@players_query` contains. Anyway, too much code, yes, move everything to models.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!

You're absolutely right. I initially had just hard-coded some seed values for @players_query, but I've refactored to parse the url request for a list of players.

I'm beginning to migrate the logic into the model. However, for the case here I need to access the Player model (e.g. Player.find_by), is it bad practice to have that logic within the Stat model? Where should that be housed?

Thanks again!

Comment: I would advise that you refactor `Stat.get_stats_of(player)` to be a standard has_many relationship. Then you can use `include` to simplify the player query.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thanks for the advice! So, are you recommending creating a many-to-many relationship between players and stats, which will ultimately allow me to query specific stats using the ActiveRecord methods?

Comment: Yes, it will look cleaner and may perform better as well.